# Powershell Nested Modules with their own manifest

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-3.0, powershell-module

I have a quick question around modules manifest. Can I have manifest for nested modules as well? Let me explain:

I have 3 modules, 1 is parent and other 2 are child. Parent module has a manifest defining 2 children under "NestedModules" section. In my main script, I load parent module and can invoke members define in parent and child modules both. Life is great till this point.

Now, if I add manifest files for child modules too, discovery becomes challenge and my main script blows out throwing error like

> "The term 'functionName' is not recognized

The rationale for adding manifest for child modules is they may become independent and can be distributed alone.

Thanks for your help!
Sam

Comment: AFAIK, you can manifest for nested modules. Can you provide [mcve], which demonstrate this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ***NestedModules*** key of Child modules' manifest was goofed up. I fixed that and voila!